# jQuery element constructor differs from using attr

Tags: jquery

jQuery 1.4 added [a shorthand way for constructing new DOM Elements](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) and filling in some of their attributes:

> `jQuery( html, props )`
>
> `html`: A string defining a single, standalone, HTML element (e.g.  or ).
>
> `props`: A map of attributes, events, and methods to call on the newly-created element.

But, I just noticed this strangeness (with jQuery 1.5.1):

```
>>> $("<img />", { height: 4 })[0].height
0
>>> $("<img />").attr({ height: 4 })[0].height
4
```

So, they are some differences between the shorthand and the longer way..! Is this a bug or is it intentional? Are there any other ones with similar behaviour which I should watch out for?

Comment: It works if the element is added to the DOM: `$("<img />", { height: 4 }).appendTo('body')[0].height`. As for *why*, I don't know. Maybe the height is not set on the DOM element before it is added to the DOM. But then the second one should not work either...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2):

> As of jQuery 1.4, the second argument
>   can accept a map consisting of a
>   superset of the properties that can be
>   passed to the `.attr()` method.
>   Furthermore, any event type can be
>   passed in, and the following jQuery
>   methods can be called: val, css, html,
>   text, data, width, height, or offset.

So basically the snippet is not equivalent to `$("<img />").attr({ height: 4 })` but to `$("<img />").height(4)` and the html it evaluates to is `<img style="height: 4px" />` - hence the returned `0`.

Comment: This is probably the correct answer. `$("<img />").height(4)[0].height` returns `0` too, so it at least explains this behaviour. *Edit: Makes totally sense now.* Would upvote more if I could :)

Comment: Might be, but it is documented.

Comment: As I said, makes sense now, as the height is set as CSS porperty. Nevertheless, when I add the image to the DOM, `$("<img />", { height: 4 }).appendTo('body')[0].height` returns `4`. But this seems to be a special `HTMLImageElement` attribute, and MDC says: *Reflects the height  HTML attribute, indicating the rendered height of the image in CSS pixels.* So it seems this value is not set until the element is really rendered.

Comment: @Felix That's probably a browser thing - I imagine it sets the height attribute of the `img` according to the css. Even if you do `img = document.createElement("img"); img.style.height = "4px"; img.height //>> 0; document.body.appendChild(img); img.height //>> 4;`

Answer (score 0):

The short way should be :

```
$("<img />", { height: 4 }).height();
```

Comment: This does not explain why the two ways behave differently. It actually does not target the question at all.

Comment: Well it shows that the shorthand method return the created element while the classic one return an array. But I agree Jakub Hampl explanation is far better.

Comment: I think you understood the question wrong. (a) This was not the point of the question and (b) both "ways" return a jQuery object. @nickf is using array access to directly access the **DOM** element.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is setting the attr will add a height attribute, the other forms set the height style property. So the shorthand version sets the style rather than the `height` attribute:

```
    $("<img />", { height: 4 });
    // creates <img style="height:4px;">


    $("<img />").height(4);
    // creates <img style="height:4px;">


    $("<img />").attr({height: 4});
    // creates <img height="4">
```

This is the case whether you append the element into the DOM or not (with jquery 1.4.4 and 1.5.1). Apologies if I'm restating something already covered in the comments.